# Why am I getting NullInjector error with Angular gauge? Even though I have included Angular Gauge module in root module

Tags: angular, gauge

ERROR Error: Uncaught (in promise): NullInjectorError: R3InjectorError(AppModule)[GaugeDefaults -> GaugeDefaults -> GaugeDefaults]:

NullInjectorError: No provider for GaugeDefaults!

NullInjectorError: R3InjectorError(AppModule)[GaugeDefaults -> GaugeDefaults -> GaugeDefaults]:

NullInjectorError: No provider for GaugeDefaults!

```
at NullInjector.get (core.mjs:11105)
at R3Injector.get (core.mjs:11272)
at R3Injector.get (core.mjs:11272)
at R3Injector.get (core.mjs:11272)
at NgModuleRef.get (core.mjs:21800)
at Object.get (core.mjs:21477)
at lookupTokenUsingModuleInjector (core.mjs:3342)
at getOrCreateInjectable (core.mjs:3454)
at Module.ɵɵdirectiveInject (core.mjs:14378)
at NodeInjectorFactory.GaugeComponent_Factory [as factory] (angular-gauge.js:109)
at resolvePromise (zone.js:1213)
at resolvePromise (zone.js:1167)
at zone.js:1279
at ZoneDelegate.invokeTask (zone.js:406)
at Object.onInvokeTask (core.mjs:25437)
at ZoneDelegate.invokeTask (zone.js:405)
at Zone.runTask (zone.js:178)
at drainMicroTaskQueue (zone.js:582)
at ZoneTask.invokeTask [as invoke] (zone.js:491)
at invokeTask (zone.js:1600)
```

defaultErrorLogger @ core.mjs:6469

Comment: Which version of angular are you using? Kindly share your App.module.ts code as well.

Comment: I am using Angular version 13.1.1.

Comment: Please edit the question to limit it to a specific problem with enough detail to identify an adequate answer.